# How to save a string in a file as a quoted string?

Tags: python, string, file, save, read-write

I have a file `file.md` that I want to read and get it as a string.
Then I want to take that string and save it in another file, but as a string with quotes (and all). The reason is I want to transfer the content of my markdown file to a markdown string so that I can include it in html using the javascript `marked` library.

How can I do that using a python script?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
with open('file.md', 'r') as md:
    text=""
    lines = md.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = "'" + line + "'" + '+'
        text = text + line
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as txt:
        txt.write(text)
```

Input `file.md`

```
This is one line of markdown
This is another line of markdown

This is another one
```

Desired output: `file.txt`

```
"This is one line of markdown" +
"This is another line of markdown" +
(what should come here by the way to encode an empty line?)
"This is another one"
```

Comment: What does your output file look like? How does it differ from what you want?

Comment: So all you want is a quote before and after the text that is read from the file?

Comment: @Jortega the thing is i think my text should need quotes at the beginning and ending of every line with a + sign that adds them up

Comment: @MAK basically i want a string in my text file

Comment: @moctarjallo Could you give an example of the desired output as it would look in the destination file?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the desired output @Jortega

Comment: I have edited the question to include the desired output @MAK

Comment: @moctarjallo If what offeltoffel answer does not work for you I have an answer that will output exactly what is described.  I did not post it because it is so close to what offeltoffel did that I would risk getting downvoted.

Comment: @Jortega: why not posting it? I think it's good to have a choice and overlook the variety of how this can be done.

Comment: Hey guys i have edited the input and ouput file expectations.

Comment: _Why_ do you think you need the quotes and + sign? This seems like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @martineau it could be. Very probably. My ultimate goal is to include my `markdown` file into my `html` file, but all in client side. For now i have discovered a javascript library `marked.js` that can just convert and include `markdown string` into my `html`. So i thought maybe my job now is just to figure out how i can convert my `markdown file` into a string, save that string into a file, copy the content of that file with the mouse and paste inside the `marked` function of javascript. So i think that's my Y solution. Have better solution, maybe using even javascript??

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to convert it to a javascript expression, which might be completely valid however I'm no expert on the topic - perhaps putting the explanation in your question would help assuming the answer you have so far doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to pay attention here.
First is that you should not change your iterator `line` while it is running through `lines`. Instead, assign it to a new string variable (I call it `new_line`). 
Second, if you add more characters at the end of each `line`, it will be placed after the end-of-line character and thus be moved into the next line when you write it to a new file. Instead, skip the last character of each line and add the line break manually.

If I understand you right, this should give you the wanted output:

```
with open('file.md', 'r') as md:
    text = ""
    lines = md.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line[-1] == "\n":
        text += "'" + line[:-1] + "'+\n"
    else:
        text += "'" + line + "'+"

with open('file.txt', 'w') as txt:
    txt.write(text)
```

Note how the last line is treated different than the others (no eol-char and no + sign).
`text += ...` adds more characters to the existing string.

This also works and might be a bit nicer, because it avoids the if-statement. You can remove the newline-character right at reading the content from `file.md`. In the end you skip the last two characters of your content, which is the `+` and the `\n`.

```
with open('file.md', 'r') as md:
    text = ""
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in md]

for line in lines:
    text += "'" + line + "' +\n"

with open('file.txt', 'w') as txt:
    txt.write(text[:-2])
```

...and with using a formatter:

```
text += "'{}' +\n".format(line)
```

...checking for empty lines as you asked in the comments:

```
for line in lines:
    if line == '':
        text += '\n'
    else:
        text += "'{}' +\n".format(line)
```

Comment: This output is close to what is described but not exactly what was described.

Comment: I just saw the edit in his question. The only difference was the blank before the `+`. Other than that it just comes down to `' '` vs. `" "`, both were proposed in the question and can easily be interchanged.

Comment: The last line should also not have a `+` at the end.

Comment: Yes, that's why `text[:-2]` is stored. second last char is `+`, last one is `\n`

Comment: Good but this is not taking into account empty lines. I've edited the question(the input and output files) to address the issue.

Comment: It does. If there is an empty line, it produces a line with an empty string like `' ' +`. Would you prefer it completely empty? You need to be precise about your desired output, so we can help you get to that exact goal.

Comment: @offeltoffel yes a completely empty line. I guess there should be a way of encoding empty into strings..

Comment: empty is just `""` with new-line-character. In this case you can't avoid the if-statement, I guess. Please find my update...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> a = '''This is one line of markdown
... This is another line of markdown
... 
... This is another one'''
>>> lines = a.split('\n')
>>> lines = [ '"' + i + '" +' if len(i) else i for i in lines]
>>> lines[-1] = lines[-1][:-2]   # drop the '+' at the end of the last line
>>> print '\n'.join( lines )
"This is one line of markdown" +
"This is another line of markdown" +

"This is another one"
```

You may add reading/writing to files yourself.